# Show limit of $n\log(1+ \frac{x}{n})$ exists

Tags: analysis, limits, derivatives

How would I do this question?

The fact that $y \rightarrow \log(1+y)$ tells me that: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log(1+0+h)-\log(1)}{h}$$ tends to a existing limit.
How do I use this for my answer??

[image]

Comment: what the hell is log(0)?

Comment: Remark : It's log(1), not log(0). Hint: use the definition with $h=\frac{1}{n}$, and notice that thanks to the sequential characterization of the limit, for any sequence $y_n \rightarrow 0$ then $\frac{log(1+0+y_n) - log(1+0)}{y_n} = \frac{log(1+y_n)}{y_n}$ must tend to $log'(1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details are not right. We want 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(1+x/n)-\log(1)}{1/n}.$$
If $x=0$, the problem is easy. If $x\ne 0$, rewrite as
$$x\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(1+x/n)-\log(1)}{x/n},$$
and let $h=x/n$. Now recognize 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\log(1+h)-\log(1)}{h}$$
as a derivative.

Comment: and how would I approach the second part?

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=(1+x/n)^n$. Then $\log f_n(x)=n\log(1+x/n)$. As we have seen, this has limit $x$. Take the exponential of both sides. Since the exponential function is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n=\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}(\log(f_n(x)))=\exp(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

What about using l'Hospital?

$$\lim_{u\to\infty} u\log\left(1+\frac xu\right)=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac xu\right)}{\frac1u}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-\frac x{u^2}\frac u{u+x}}{-\frac1{u^2}}=x\cdot 1=x\;$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rewrite

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
 as 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
and then apply L'Hopital's rule

Comment: and in this case you would differentiate w.r.t. $n$?

Comment: @Kimo yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

$$n\geqslant 2|x|\implies x-x^2/n\leqslant n\log(1+x/n)\leqslant x$$